# Customizing Spring CAS j_spring_cas_security_check URL

Tags: spring-security, cas, spring-security-cas

I'm using CAS 3.5.2 and Spring CAS extension. I'm trying to change `j_spring_cas_security_check` (and similar one for logout) URL to something like `security_check`. I read in [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/cas.html) that

```
Back in the service web application, the CasAuthenticationFilter is always listening for
requests to /j_spring_cas_security_check (this is configurable, but we'll use the defaults   
in this introduction).
```

I thought this was just a dummy URL that can be changed by setting it as a value of the `service` property of `org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties` bean in my Spring Security configuration, but after changing that my CAS `SSO` started breaking. I didn't see any exceptions on the client or server side.

Are there any obvious steps I'm missing while changing this default path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the code of `CasAuthenticationFilter` and found out that `filterProcessesUrl` needs to be set to the custom URL. The default is set in the constructor as /j_spring_cas_security_check.